# Setting Trend Line Length in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, trendline

I have managed to create a scatterplot with two datasets on a single plot. One set of data has an X axis that ranges from 0 -40 (Green), while the other only ranges from 0 -15 (Red).

[image: (http://s9.postimg.org/fw48s8rq7/Rplot.jpg)]

I used this code to add trend lines to the red and green data separately (using par(new)).

```
plot( x1,y1, col="red", axes=FALSE, xlab="",ylab="",ylim= range(0:1), xlim= range(0:40))
f <- function(x1,a,b,d) {(a*x1^2) + (b*x1) + d}
fit <- nls(y1 ~ f(x1,a,b,d), start = c(a=1, b=1, d=1)) 
co <- coef(fit)
curve(f(x, a=co[1], b=co[2], d=co[3]), add = TRUE, col="red", lwd=1)
```

My issue is I can't seem to find a way to stop the red trend line at 15 on the x axis. I "googled" around and nothing seemed to come up for my issue. Lots on excel trend lines! I tired adding an end= statement to fit<- and that did not work either.

Please help,

I hope I have posted enough information.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @nograpes. I was not able to post the picture due to my lack of experience points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in base graphics with the `from` and `to` arguments of the `curve` function (see the help for `curve` for more details). For example:

```
# Your function
f <- function(x1,a,b,d) {(a*x1^2) + (b*x1) + d}

# Plot the function from x=-100 to x=100
curve(f(x, a=-2, b=3, d=0), from=-100, to=100, col="red", lwd=1, lty=1)

# Same curve going from x=-100 to x=0 (and shifted down by 1000 units so it's
# easy to see)
curve(f(x, a=-2, b=3, d=-1000), from=-100, to=0, 
      add=TRUE, col="blue", lwd=2, lty=1)
```

[image]

If you want to set the curve x-limits programmatically, you can do something like this (assuming your data frame is called `df` and your x-variable is called `x`):

```
curve(f(x, a=-2, b=3, d=0), from=range(df$x)[1], to=range(df$x)[2], 
       add=TRUE, col="red", lwd=1, lty=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using ggplot. Following example uses mtcars data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt, color=factor(vs)))+geom_point()+ stat_smooth(se=F)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can just do `geom_smooth(se=FALSE)` instead of the two `stat_smooth` calls.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried it earlier but it did not work because at that time I was using color=vs rather than color=factor(vs)

Comment: Also good to know. Thank you for the reply. I haven't quite got the handle on ggplot yet and all my other graphs are in the same format as above.